# Merge arrays from different objects with same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, spread-syntax

I have the following code:

```
const blueData = {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "revision": 1,
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T14:29:54.595012Z",
        },
    ]
}

const redData = {}

const greenData = {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 36,
            "revision": 1,
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T14:31:07.164368Z",
        }
    ]
}

let colorData = []
colorData = blueData.items ? [colorData, ...blueData.items] : colorData
colorData = redData.items ? [colorData, ...redData.items] : colorData
colorData = greenData.items ? [colorData, ...greenData.items] : colorData
```

I am guessing the spread operator is not the right approache here as I'm getting some extra arrays in my final `colorData` array. I simply want to build a single array of 'items' that contains all of the 'items' from the 3 objects.

Here's a link to that code in es6 console: https://es6console.com/ktkhc3j2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your data into an array then use `flatMap` to unwrap each `.items`:

```
[greenData, redData, blueData].flatMap(d => d.items ?? [])
//=> [ {id: 36, revision: 1, updatedAt: '2021-09-10T14:31:07.164368Z'}
//=> , {id: 35, revision: 1, updatedAt: '2021-09-10T14:29:54.595012Z'}]
```

If you fancy you could abstract `d => d.items ?? []` with a bit of curry (no pun intended ;)

```
const take = k => o => o[k] ?? [];
```

Which gives us:

```
[greenData, redData, blueData].flatMap(take('items'))
```

We can even go a step further if you ever need to repeat this process with different keys:

```
const concatBy = fn => xs => xs.flatMap(x => fn(x));
```

Now it almost feels like you're expressing your intent with words instead of code:

```
const takeItems = concatBy(take('items'));

takeItems([greenData, redData, blueData]);
//=> [ {id: 36, revision: 1, updatedAt: '2021-09-10T14:31:07.164368Z'}
//=> , {id: 35, revision: 1, updatedAt: '2021-09-
```

Let's build another function:

```
const takeFood = concatBy(take('food'));

takeFood([{food: ['', '']}, {food: ['', '']}]);
//=> ['', '', '', '']
```

---

**Addendum**

*This is only meant as a potentially useful learning material. My advice is to use `flatMap`.*

This:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].flatMap(x => x)
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Can also be expressed with `reduce`. Slightly more verbose but does what it says on the tin:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].reduce((xs, x) => xs.concat(x), [])
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So to put it simply you could also do:

```
[greenData, redData, blueData].reduce((xs, x) => xs.concat(x.items ?? []), [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`Logical OR operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) which lets you provide a default value if the `items` field is missing.

```js
const blueData = { items: [ { id: 35, revision: 1, updatedAt: '2021-09-10T14:29:54.595012Z', }, ], };
const redData = {};
const greenData = { items: [ { id: 36, revision: 1, updatedAt: '2021-09-10T14:31:07.164368Z', }, ], };

const colorData = [
  ...(blueData.items || []),
  ...(redData.items || []),
  ...(greenData.items || []),
];

console.log(colorData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a little old-fashioned but I'd use `concat` for that:

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

```js
const blueData = {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "revision": 1,
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T14:29:54.595012Z",
        },
    ]
}

const redData = {}

const greenData = {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 36,
            "revision": 1,
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T14:31:07.164368Z",
        }
    ]
}


const colorData = [].concat(blueData.items,redData.items,greenData.items).filter(x => x)

console.log(colorData)
```

the last `filter` is for removing undefined values

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
colorData = blueData.items ? [...colorData, ...blueData.items] : colorData
colorData = redData.items ? [...colorData, ...redData.items] : colorData
colorData = greenData.items ? [...colorData, ...greenData.items] : colorData
```

Output:

```
[{"id":35,"revision":1,"updatedAt":"2021-09-10T14:29:54.595012Z"}, 
{"id":36,"revision":1,"updatedAt":"2021-09-10T14:31:07.164368Z"}]
```

I think you need to add the spread operator also to the `colorData` array, because if not you are adding the `colorData` array itself, not its items.

Comment: This is perfect (just have to wait a few minutes before accepting your answer).
Is there a shorter way to write:
`colorData = blueData.items ? [...colorData, ...blueData.items] : colorData`
so that colorData just remains colorData if the ternary conditional is false?

Comment: you can have a look to the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Chaging the `||` by the `??` you check specifically for `null` or `undefined` values, instead of any falsy values in which `null` and `undefined` are included ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the simplest solution, you can iterate with a for-loop between all arrays. Create a temporary array that will store data found on each index. This is the fastest and the most flexible solution.

```js
var x1 = {
  "items": [
    { "testKey1": "testVal" }
  ] 
};

var x2 = {
  "items": [
    { "testKey2.0": "testVal2" },
    { "testKey2.1": "testVal2" },
    { "testKey2.2": "testVal2" },
  ] 
};

var x3 = {
  "items": [
    { "testKey3.0": "testVal3" },
    { "testKey3.1": "testVal3" }
  ] 
};

function combineArrays(...arrays) {

  var tempArray = [];
  for (let index in arrays) {
    let currentArray = arrays[index];
    for (let innerArrayIndex in currentArray) {
      tempArray.push(currentArray[innerArrayIndex]);
    }
  } 
  
  return tempArray;
}

var result = combineArrays(x1.items, x2.items, x3.items);
console.log(result);
```

*The solutions using a spread operator do not take into consideration that all the objects will be cloned using a shallow copy. [Have a look](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-javascript-spread-operator-from-beginner-to-expert-8f1c110c64db).*

Comment: I think the OP is more after the solution for the specific problem and readability, anyhow very nice article + pokemon examples! :)

Comment: `The solutions using a spread operator do not take into consideration that all the objects will be cloned using a shallow copy.` — I'm not sure why you say that; your current solution doesn't clone anything at all. Not saying it's wrong though! Only an observation that your solution isn't mutation-proof either.

Comment: @customcommander If you want to be mutation-proof you can shallow copy (clone) the resulting array. Cloning each array and then merging seems to me like an overhead.